# Model theory of intuistionistic logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory, proof-theory, intuitionistic-logic

1. The [Tarskian interpretation of first order logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Semantic_theory_of_truth&oldid=1075467005#Tarski%27s_theory_of_truth), $I=I_{S,\alpha}$, where $S$ is a first order structure w.r.t. the signature $\Sigma$, and $\alpha$ is a variable assignment, assign either $T$ or $F$ to every w.f.f. $\varphi$ over $\Sigma$. Is there a similar standard interpretation of intuistionistic logic?
2. The following question is only relevant assuming there is a standard interpretation of intuistionistic logic, $J$. Tarski's $I$ satisfies that $I\big(\neg(\varphi)\big)=\neg I(\varphi)$ (where $\neg T=F$, and $\neg F=T$), and that $\varphi$ is provable per Gentzen's Natural Deduction iff $I(\varphi)=T$. How does $J$ compare to $I$ in these regards?

Comment: There are different semantics for intutionstic logic.

Comment: @VioletFlame Please elaborate.

Comment: Do you know about Heyting algebras (analogue of Boolean algebras) and Kripke semantics?

Comment: @Trebor No, I don't.

Comment: See [Kripke semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kripke_semantics) and [Intuitionistic Logic: Semantics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/#BasSem)

Comment: Re 2. Yes; the usual proof systems for Intuitionistic Logic [Natural deduction, Hilbert-style, Sequent Calculus, Tableaux] are sound and complete for the corresponding semantics.

Comment: Obviously, the different semantics for IL shares the "basic features", e.g. they do not validate LEM; this means that they all differ in some relevant aspect from classical semantics.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as if you need a good intro to intuitionistic logic with, in particular, a discussion of (at least) the now standard Kripke semantics.

So take a look at e.g. Ch. 8 “Intuitionistic logic” of the *Beginning Mathematical Logic* Study Guide, which you can freely download at https://logicmatters.net/tyl

The chapter begins with a brief 8-page outline of the syntax and semantics of intuitionistic logic (including the so-called BHK interpretation and Kripke semantics), and explains why excluded middle fails on these semantic accounts. Then  §8.4 suggests some further readings which will tell you a bit more.